# c++ autoconvert inherited class to base class

Tags: c++

I have one problem on conversion of one class to base.
This is the code :

```
    #define Derive_NTag_CRTP(Type) class Type: public NTagBase<Type>

template<typename Derived>
class NTagBase{
public:
    NTagBase(var name) { this->_name = name; }
    NTagBase(const NTagBase & ntag) { this->_name = ntag._name; }
    NTagBase* append(NTagBase<Derived> *item) { _children.push_back(item); return this; }
private:
    var _name;
    vector<NTagBase *> _children;
};

Derive_NTag_CRTP(NTag){
public:
    NTag(var name) : NTagBase(name) { }
    NTag(const NTagBase & ntag) : NTagBase(ntag) {  }
};

Derive_NTag_CRTP(NTagInput){
public:
    NTagInput(var type) : NTagBase("input") { _type = type; } 
    NTagInput(const NTagBase & ntag) : NTagBase(ntag) {  }
private:
    var _type;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envv)
{

    NTag div("div");
    NTagInput button("button");
    div.append(new NTag("span"));

    div.append(&button);// Error    1   error C2664: 'NTagBase<Derived>::append': can not convert parameter 1 from 'NTagInput *' to 'NTagBase<Derived> *'

    }
```

How can I fix that without do one explicit cast?

PS: I need to have one vector of pointers of base class and append into that all kind of classes inherited.

Comment: Do you want `vector<NTagBase*> _children` ? (to avoid possible slicing)

Comment: I want to append a button object to div but button object is NTagInput and not NTagBase

Comment: BTW: `NTagInput` (`: public NTagBase<NTagInput>`) is different than `NTagBase<NTag>`. NTagBase may derive from a common base to allow what you want.

Comment: What is the purpose of CRTP here ?

Comment: I need of crtp for return my correct type from append method

Comment: You don't do that currently.

Answer (score 0):

`div` is `NTag`, i.e. `NTagBase<NTag>`. `button` is `NTagInput`, i.e. `NTagBase<NTagInput>`, while `div`'s `append()` expects a `NTagBase<NTag>` which is unrelated. You should change `append` to something like

```
template <typename D>
NTagBase* append(NTagBase<D> item) { ... }
```

However, you still cannot store items of different types in a single vector. Better make a non-template e.g. `Base` of `NTagBase` and let your vector contain pointers (or `std::unique_ptr`) to `Base`.

Comment: I have updated the code with a vector pointer and a typename for append method. But I still get the error.

Comment: @pava91 You should either make `append` a template function or let it accept a pointer/reference to a common (probably non-template) base class. It still expects the wrong type of argument.

Answer (score 0):

`div.append (...)` clearly need to be overloaded because after inherited from the base, it wouldn't understand the second signature ie `div.append(&button);` or you can create a wrapper class that pack every object type to it own define and provide a mechanism for reversing back to the original type.

Alternatively , just overload any necessary function .

```
class NTagInput;
class AppendInputRegister;


template<typename Derived>
class NTagBase{
    public:
        NTagBase(string name) { this->_name = name; }
        NTagBase(const NTagBase & ntag) { this->_name = ntag._name; }
        NTagBase* append(NTagBase<Derived>  *item) {
             _children.push_back((NTagBase *)item);
              return this;
        }
    private:
        string _name;
        vector<NTagBase *> _children;
};

class NTag: public NTagBase<NTag>{
    public:
        NTag(string name) : NTagBase(name) { }
        NTag(const NTagBase & ntag) : NTagBase(ntag) {  }

        NTagBase* append(NTagBase<NTagInput>  *item) {
             append((NTagBase<NTag> *)item);
        }

        NTagBase* append(NTagBase<NTag>  *item) {
             NTagBase::append((NTagBase<NTag> *)item);
        }

};

class NTagInput: public NTagBase<NTagInput>{
    public:
        NTagInput(string type) : NTagBase("input") { _type = type; }
        NTagInput(const NTagBase & ntag) : NTagBase(ntag) {  }
    private:
        string _type;
};
```